# Accessing private/protected method with generic type using reflection

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I have a class with a validate method that contains generic type

```
public class Foo{
private <T> validateThis(T objectToValidate)
{
Set<ConstraintViolation<T>> constraintViolations;
try
        {
            constraintViolations = validator.validate(objectToValidate);
        }
        catch(RuntimeException re)
        {
            throw new HttpStatusUnprocessableEntityException("Unexpected problem occurred);
        }  
}
```

however I want to access this method using reflection (i.e for unit testing ) 
but when I try

```
Method method = 
Foo.class.getDeclaredMethod("validateThis",ParameterizedType.class);
method.setAccessible(true);
```

I am getting

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:Foo.validateThis(java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType)
```

Comment: Generics are erased as runtime... Try using `Foo.class.getDeclaredMethod("validateThis",Object.class);`

Comment: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339699/java-generics-type-erasure-when-and-what-happens) for more bout type erasure